# How can i send property value as object value?

Tags: angular

I am having component where i am sending `data`  for my input property there.

I am sending object in my `data` input property in FormGroup component.

```
<app-form-group shouldTheInputBeDisabled='false' formControlName="salary" [data]="{ field: 'salary', label: 'Specify the salary for' + ' ' +  'John' }"></app-form-group>
```

i want to make my label dynamically. Here John is hardcoded - but i should get the value from `userName` property from my component - `the typescript file`.

Is there some way that i gen generate this through HTML?  I tried

```
[data]="{ field: 'salary', label: 'Specify the salary for' + ' ' +  `${userName}` }"
```

but without success.

I know that i can prepare all of this in my `ts file` and after that just send that
prepaired in the child component, but i wonder can this be done in the html directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use template literals inside Angular templates.
Using your example, you'd have to concatenate the string directly:

```
[data]="{ field: 'salary', label: 'Specify the salary for ' + userName }"
```

Comment: Thank you.Is there a way with which i can use uppercase pipe in my example on userName directly here ?